# using output from beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey all, I am using beautifulsoup (after unsuccessfully struggling for two days with scrapy) to scrape starcraft 2 league data however I am encountering a problem.

I have this table with the result of which I want the string content of all  tags which i do like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
from urllib import urlopen

def parseWithSoup(url):
    print "Reading:" , url
    html = urlopen(url).read().lower()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = bs.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_key('id') and tag['id']=="tblt_table") 
    rows = table.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')

    rows.pop(0) #first row is header
    for row in rows:
        tags = row.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='a')
        content = []
        for tagcontent in tags:
            content.append(tagcontent.string)
        print content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    content = "http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-international/games#tblt-5018-1-1-DESC"
    metSoup = parseWithSoup(content)
```

however the output is as follows:

```
[u'+', u'gadget show live i..', u'crevasse', u'naniwa', u'socke']
[u'+', u'gadget show live i..', u'metalopolis 1.1', u'naniwa', u'socke']
[u'+', u'gadget show live i..', u'shakuras plateau 2.0', u'socke', u'select']
etc...
```

My question is: where does the u'' come from (is it from unicode?) and how can I remove this? I just need the strings that are in u''...

Comment: >>> l = [u'+', u'gadget show live i..', u'crevasse', u'naniwa', u'socke']
>>> l[1]
u'gadget show live i..'.

>>> print l[1] #still unicode but as you with print no u
gadget show live i..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `u` means Unicode string. It doesn't change anything for you as a programmer and you should just disregard it. Treat them like normal strings. You actually want this u there.

Be aware that all Beautiful Soup output is unicode. That's a good thing, because if you run across any Unicode characters in your scraping, you won't have any problems. If you *really* want to get rid of the `u`, (I don't recommend it), you can use the unicode string's `decode()` method.

Comment: Just really curious: why wouldn't you recommend it? Eventually I want to output this into a .csv file, I don't want the u's to be there (or will this be taken care of automatically?)

Comment: @Javaaa it's just part of the representation when Python shows you the data structure. It doesn't actually show up if you output to stdout or a file.

Comment: You can not convert unicode strings to standard strings using str(). This is the typical US-advice where people only know ASCII. For converting unicode strings properly to a string you need to use the some_unicode_string.decode(encoding) method.  Calling str() on a unicode string is *never* appropriate.

Comment: @RestRisiko please don't misinterpret my ignorance of unicode as some kind of racism.

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble eliminating the u from a list of data with strings which contained numbers and I couldn't really figure out why it was there and what it meant.

Answer (score 0):

What you see are Python unicode strings.

Check the Python documentation

http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

in order to deal correctly with unicode strings.

Comment: this all makes a lot of sense now, had the same problem in another project using tweepy, thanks!